# Find the highest and lowest value of each person if the person is more than one

Tags: c

i want to find the highest and lowest of each person final results of percentage,sum,project,MID,Final and grade with searching method.

```
struct student{
  char id[10];
  char fname[25];
  char lname[25];
  char letter[10];
  int quiz[3];
  int assignment[3];
  int project,MID,Final,grade,percentage,average,sum;
};

int main() {
  struct student person[10];
  int input,choose,max=0,min=0;

  printf("Input Student : ");
  scanf("%d",&input );
  printf("\n");

  int i,j,k,g;
  for ( i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    int count=0,count2=0;
    printf("Input Id : ");
    scanf("%s",person[i].id);
    printf("Input Name : ");
    scanf("%s",person[i].fname);
    scanf("%s",person[i].lname);
    printf("\n");

    //input assignment
    for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      printf("Input Assignment%d : ",j );
      scanf("%d",&person[i].assignment[j] );
      count+=person[i].assignment[j];
      person[i].average = count/3;
    }
    person[i].percentage = person[i].average*0.20;
    person[i].MaxPer = person[i].percentage;

    printf("\n");
    //input quiz
    for ( k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
      printf("Input Quiz%d : ",k );
      scanf("%d",&person[k].quiz[i] );
      count2+=person[k].quiz[i];
      person[i].average = count2/4;
    }
    person[i].sum = person[i].average*0.10;
    person[i].MinPer = person[i].percentage;

    printf("\n");

    //input Project
    printf("Input Project Value%d : ",i );
    scanf("%d",&person[i].project );
    person[i].project= person[i].project * 0.15;
    printf("\n");

    //input MID
    printf("Input Project Value%d : ",i );
    scanf("%d",&person[i].MID );
    fflush(stdin);
    person[i].MID= person[i].MID * 0.25;
    printf("\n");

    //input Final
    printf("Input Project Value%d : ",i );
    scanf("%d",&person[i].Final );
    fflush(stdin);
    person[i].Final= person[i].Final * 0.25;

    //count Grade
    person[i].grade = person[i].percentage + person[i].sum + person[i].project + person[i].MID + person[i].Final;

    printf("\n");
  }

      printf("Highest Value \t\t\t%15d %25d %11d %10d %10d\n",person[i].MaxPer,person[i].sum,person[i].project,person[i].MID,person[i].Final);
      printf("Lowest Value \t\t\t%15d %25d %11d %10d %10d\n",person[i].MinPer,person[i].sum,person[i].project,person[i].MID,person[i].Final);
  return 0;
}
```

so if i input all the assignment,quiz,etc for 3 person with different number,it will loop and find the highest and lowest among the three.And the last is to print the output.

Comment: What is going wrong with your code?

Comment: i want to add the logic the fidn the highest and lowest number, but i'm confusing to use searchin method in c

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this information instead of answering in comments. Please also show what input you use, what output you actually get and what you want to get for the example input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want to find the highest and lowest of each person final results of percentage,sum,project,MID,Final and grade with searching method.

I do not understand what you mean because a lot of these data are unique for each person so how to speak about min/max on them ? Are you speaking about min/max among all the persons ?

Anyway some remarks on your code hopping they will help you

---

Warning the two lines

> ```
>  printf("Highest Value \t\t\t%15d %25d %11d %10d %10d\n",person[i].MaxPer,person[i].sum,person[i].project,person[i].MID,person[i].Final);
>  printf("Lowest Value \t\t\t%15d %25d %11d %10d %10d\n",person[i].MinPer,person[i].sum,person[i].project,person[i].MID,person[i].Final);
> ```

are out of `for ( i = 0; i < input; i++) {` so *i* values *input* and you access to not initialized values and may be out of *person*

In

> scanf("%d",&input );

you do not check *scanf* returns 1 to know if the input was a valid number, you need also to check if *input* is less than 10 else you will access out of the array, anyway to also check the value is positive to indicate an error else seems a good idea.

Also check the other *scanf* to know if a valid input was done, never suppose a user enter a valid input

The fields *MaxPer* and *MinPer* do not exist but also in

> ```
>  person[i].MaxPer = person[i].percentage;
>
>  printf("\n");
>  //input quiz
>  for ( k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
>    printf("Input Quiz%d : ",k );
>    scanf("%d",&person[k].quiz[i] );
>    count2+=person[k].quiz[i];
>    person[i].average = count2/4;
>  }
>  person[i].sum = person[i].average*0.10;
>  person[i].MinPer = person[i].percentage;
> ```

`person[i].percentage;` is unchanged so *MaxPer* and *MinPer* will have the same value

why are you setting `person[i].average` in the loop rather than after ?

why `*0.10`

Same thing in

> ```
>  for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
>    printf("Input Assignment%d : ",j );
>    scanf("%d",&person[i].assignment[j] );
>    count+=person[i].assignment[j];
>    person[i].average = count/3;
>  }
>  person[i].percentage = person[i].average*0.20;
> ```

why are you setting `person[i].average` in the loop rather than after ?

why `person[i].average*0.20;` like if you managed 5 values ?